# Чи існує слово "першопочаток"?

Tags: значення-слів, існування-слова

Десь натрапив на слово "першопочаток".

Шукаю в [ґуґлі](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=lang_uk&biw=1366&bih=657&tbs=lr%3Alang_1uk&ei=ZivOW4quPIavsQG-iahI&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%22&oq=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1j0j0i30k1l3.321.1608.0.1827.2.2.0.0.0.0.92.166.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.164....0.w7AdL3oeRlc) в лапках і "лише українською". Видає 5550 результатів. Отже слово досить активно, як на таке складне, вживається.

З іншого боку, ані в СУМ-11, ані в Грінченка, ані в Єфремова з Кримським тощо такого слова не знаходжу. Бачу його лише в словниках з відмінками й формами слова загалом і у "Російсько-українському народному сучасному словнику", якому не йму віри, бо народний, сучасний, незрозуміло ким наповнений.

Питання просте. Чи існує в українській мові слово "першопочаток", а чи це помилка, вживати його? Якщо існує, то яке має значення, і де то значення можна подивитися.

Answer (score 3):

Спершу я вирішив також пошукати в [ЕСУМ](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf)і, однак там цього слова я не знайшов, проте наткнувася на нього в [Орфографічному словнику](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=230965) української мови. Часто зустрічається це слово у статтях та роботах пов'язаних із філософією (наприклад [тут](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96), де логос - це духовний першопочаток), а також можна зустріти це слово, наприклад, у вірші І. Світличного:

> гримить суремно і громово
>
> Першопочаток  чину  —  слово

І все, на жаль якихось офіційних джерел, які б підтверджували, що це слово є в українській мові я не знайшов. Однак, враховуючи, що у нас є такі слова як [першоелемент](http://sum.in.ua/s/pershoelement) та [першооснова](http://sum.in.ua/s/pershoosnova), то гадаю, що теоретично і слово "першопочаток" також може існувати в українській мові і не перечитиме правилам українського словотвору.